# Compact way to create Guava Multimaps?

Tags: java, generics, guava

If I want to create a new `Multimap` with simple defaults, I curently need to do something like:

```
private final Multimap<Key, Value> providersToClasses = Multimaps
        .newListMultimap(
                new HashMap<Key, Collection<Value>>(),
                new Supplier<List<Value>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<Value> get() {
                        return Lists.newArrayList();
                    }
                });
```

...because Java can't infer the correct types if `Maps.newHashMap` is used for the backing map. Of course, this can be refactored into a separate method, but is there already a way to write it more concisely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Guava documentation](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/24.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#create--) states that the `create` method advocated by some other answers **"will soon be deprecated"** in favour of the different forms presented below, and should therefore be avoided.

From **Guava 21.0 onwards**, the recommended way of creating a `Multimap` object where values are stored in `ArrayList` collections is the following:

```
MultimapBuilder.hashKeys().arrayListValues().build();
```

You can also use parameters if you want to specify the expected number of keys in your map and the expected number of values per key:

```
MultimapBuilder.hashKeys(expectedKeys).arrayListValues(expectedValuesPerKey).build();
```

Finally, you can create a new `Multimap` from an existing one using this construct:

```
MultimapBuilder.hashKeys().arrayListValues().build(multimap);
```

If you want to use data structures other than `ArrayLists` in your `Multimap`, you can replace the call to `arrayListValues()` by a number of other ones, listed [here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/24.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.MultimapBuilderWithKeys.html).

Comment: `MultimapBuilder` is still marked `@Beta` as of 27.0.

Comment: In 28.0/28.1 it isn't (but `create` still "will soon be deprecated")

Answer (score 62):

Why aren't you using [`ArrayListMultimap.create()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#create()) for such a simple case? It's the default way to create the simple HashMap/ArrayList that is probably the most common used multimap.

Comment: I think you mean `ArrayListMultimap`.  `HashMultimap` is for `HashMap`/`HashSet`.

Comment: We were concerned about this, so we put this doc on newListMultimap(): "Call this method only when the simpler methods ArrayListMultimap.create() and LinkedListMultimap.create() won't suffice."

Comment: Hi, @KevinBourrillion. Forcing that factory parameter creates lots of noise for sometimes very simple usecases. What would be very useful to have simplified version, something like that NewListMultimap(Map<K,Collection<V>> map) which would create multiMaps using some default factory. I have lot's MultivaluedMap classes from Jersey to convert to multimaps and that conversion code   makes it very difficult to read the code.

Comment: As of version 21.0, the documentation states that this method will be deprecated, in favor of ```MultimapBuilder.hashKeys().arrayListValues().build()```.

Answer (score 26):

I run into this problem when writing clients and building up maps of query params. A nice succinct pattern I like for constructing multi-maps is to use [`ImmutableMultiMap#builder`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultimap.html#builder())

```
Multimap<String, String> queryParams = 
  ImmutableMultimap.<String, String>builder()
    .put("key-1", "value-1")
    .put("key-1", "value-2")
    .build();
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is compact solution:

```
Multimap<Integer, String> multi = HashMultimap.create();
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8 this is much nicer, for all kinds of multimaps. This is for two reasons:

- Because the compiler uses [target types for type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), you don't have to provide explicit type arguments for the `HashMap` contructor.
- [Constructor method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) can be used to create the `ArrayList` factory.

It looks like this:

```
Multimap<Key, Value> providersToClasses =
    Multimaps.newListMultimap(new HashMap<>(), ArrayList::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the original type inference problem, though, you can also specify the generic types on a static method using `Maps.<Key, Collection<Value>>newHashMap()`, but it's certainly not more concise than `new HashMap<Key, Collection<Value>>()` (it may be more consistent).